# Set rvm default interpreter in user's .rvmrc?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm curious if it's possible to set my default Ruby interpreter within my `$HOME/.rvmrc` file (i.e. the equivalent of a `rvm --default use 1.9.2`).

I tried setting `rvm_ruby_interpreter` and `rvm_ruby_version`, but no luck.

Comment: Any reason not to just put `rvm --default use 1.9.2` in the `.bashrc` or `.profile` or whatever?

Comment: No not really. I was just curious as I was updating my dotfiles and don't really see `.rvmrc`'s used outside of project-level scopes. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cleaning out my unanswered questions... I ended up basically taking Phrogz's suggestion and adding this to my `.zprofile`:

```
RVM_DEFAULT=ruby-1.9.3-p194@home
if [ -x ~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt ] && [ "$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt)" != $RVM_DEFAULT ] ; then
  rvm use $RVM_DEFAULT
fi
```

Looking back it's kind of a weird question, probably due to the fact that I was new to rvm and relatively new to Ruby (but familiar with Unix and dotfiles).

Answer (score 0):

You can't in the $HOME/.rvmrc or /etc/rvmrc file, but you can in project .rvmrc files by typing in `rvm <interpreter>`. So if you want 1.9.2 for one project, but ree for a different, type in `rvm 1.9.2` in the first project's .rvmrc file, and `rvm ree` in the other project's .rvmrc file. You can also automatically activate gemsets this way.

Source: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: Yes, I am aware of project-level .rvmrc settings. It's too bad that it apparently can't be done in the $HOME/.rvmrc. Ah well

Comment: What version of RVM are you using? I have a user level .rvmrc file with `rvm ree` which works perfectly

Comment: .rvmrc is for root, doesn't appear to work for other users, weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you have projects using .rvmrc (or .ruby-version / .ruby-gemset), and want to be sure your home directory sets those envars to something else (no matter how many times you cd here and there), try this in ~/.bashrc:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $PWD = $HOME ]] && (rvm use default; rvm gemset use global) > /dev/null'
```

Substituting your favorite flavors for `default` and `global`, of course.